# How to change the name of the subdirectory in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have installed WordPress in: `http://site.pt/wordpress/`, but I wanted to change the name to `http://site.pt/home/` so that the homepage will be the same address and  all the other pages like `http://site.pt/home/page1`, `http://site.pt/home/page2`.

I have tried changing the folder name and the link in the WordPress site options, but to no success.

I have tried to change the "Site Address (URL)" and "WordPress Address (URL)" to `http://site.pt/home/` in the general options of WordPress, and then changing the name of the WordPress folder to `home`, it worked for the homepage, but then all the other pages give an error.

Answer (score 1):

Install "All in one migration" plugin in your current site. Export it then make a directory where you want to upload current site. Install WordPress and All in on migration and then import. You're done

Comment: Yeh this works and I have done it a few times, but I wanted to know if I can just move the content insted of creating a new one and import every thing.

Comment: you'll need to take backup of your site's database as well as site data backup. and then move all folder and files from one directory to another (wherever you want to copy)

Answer (score 1):

Now, all you need to do is reset permalink and change /wordpress/ to /home/ in the .htaccess file.

Comment: In the root or the sub directory?